# How to compare the shape of one SortedSet to another in C#

Tags: c#, compare, binary-tree, sortedset

I'm trying to compare the shape (by shape, I mean the shape of the binary tree) of one SortedSet at a certain index of a List of SortedSets against all the rest of the SortedSets in that same List. I've tried to look up ways to compare Binary Trees, but I don't know how to do it with SortedSets instead. (Recursion also confuses the crap outa me!)

```
    //Checks shape of the trees
    public static bool compareShape(List<SortedSet<int>> trees, SortedSet<int> currentTree)
    {
        //COMPARE SHAPE WITH REST OF LIST
        for (int i = 0; i < trees.Count(); i++)
        {
            // Empty trees are equal
            if (trees[i] == null && currentTree == null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            // Empty tree is not equal to a non-empty one
            if ((trees[i] == null && currentTree != null) || (trees[i] != null && currentTree == null))
            {
                return false;
            }

            // otherwise check recursively
            return compareShape(trees[i].left(), currentTree.left()) && compareShape(trees[i].right(), currentTree.right());
        }

    }
}
```

The code inside of the 'for' loop is inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741900/binary-trees-question-checking-for-similar-shape) other question about comparing Binary Trees. Sorry if this is kind of hard to understand. I would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: First question to ask: how to implement BinaryTree with .NET. Code in question does not compile with System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet

Comment: Yea. The code doesn't compile because it's trying to perform recursion with messed up values for compareShape's parameters. I just put in what I thought was the right idea, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: I have looked into implementing a Binary Tree, but if I did that I would have to rewrite my whole program. Instead, I want to see if I can finish it with what I have.

Comment: I made [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48491061/5789864), where I hope you can get idea for recursive comparing function. I did not include your for-loop in recursive function, because it added too much complexity in it. You can have for-loop outside you search function. Hopefully this helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example implementation of shape-comparing method with imaginary BinaryTree-class.

Recursive function works best when it is as simple as possible and when there is no any extra logic included. In your algorithm, you tried to include array looping and became excessive complex because of that.

```
public abstract class BinaryTree<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public BinaryTree<T> Left { get; set; }
    public BinaryTree<T> Right { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Checks shape of the trees
/// </summary>
public static bool CompareTreeShapes(BinaryTree<int> tree1, BinaryTree<int> tree2)
{
    // Empty trees are equal
    if (tree1 == null && tree2 == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    // Empty tree is not equal to a non-empty one
    if ((tree1 == null) != (tree2 == null))
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Otherwise check recursively both parts: left and right
    return CompareTreeShapes(tree1.Left, tree2.Left) && CompareTreeShapes(tree1.Right, tree2.Right);
}
```

Now when you have *CompareTreeShapes*-function and you can start using it in more complex algorithms.